# Show that x = (66B − 65a) mod 143.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For each natural number $m$ we define $J_m = \{0, 1, . . . , m − 1\}$, the set of all possible
residues modulo $m$.

Let $x \in J_{143}$.

Define
$a \equiv x \pmod{11}$, $B \equiv x \pmod{13}$

Show that $x = (66B − 65a) \pmod{143}$.

I have no idea how to get started on this problem any tips or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chinese Remainder Theorem guarantees that your congruences have a unique solution modulo $143$.  So, just check that the given formula for $x$ works.  For example,
$$66b-65a\equiv0b-(-1)a\equiv a\pmod{11}\ .$$